# how to list chef nodes that are not pingable - knife

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef, knife

I have bunch of ec2 nodes registered to chef server, more than half of them were terminated earlier. I still see them as nodes under knife node list. How do I delete them that are not pingable? 
My clients are not running chef-client periodically, it is adhoc.

Comment: Looks like you're asking for [this fine knife hack](https://github.com/stevendanna/knife-hacks/blob/master/exec/clean-ec2-cruft.rb).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to run `knife status` as a built-in solution. It gives you your nodes ordered by last check-in time.